# R gsub multiple conditions

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to use gsub on a set of strings that might all vary in the wording slightly;

```
I went to the store last night
I went to the park yesterday
I went to starbucks this morning
```

I need to use gsub to replace the 'I went to...', but sometimes it will have a 'the' and sometimes it won't

Something like this, but the following won't work properly

```
gsub('i went to [the|a-z]','REPLACED',string)

REPLACED last night
REPLACED yesterday
REPLACED this morning
```

Comment: Something like this? `gsub("I went to[ the]*(store|park|starbucks)","REPLACED",data)`

Comment: @user2100721 He put it in the second code block I believe.

Comment: @user2100721 it is in the second block. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
gsub("I went to (the )?[a-z]", "REPLACED", string)
```

Comment: This leaves the store|park|starbucks in the string

Comment: As I understand, this kind of output was expected

Comment: As I understood, `REPLACED last night
REPLACED yesterday
REPLACED this morning` was expected

Comment: You can use `I went to (the )?[a-z]*` to remove store|park|starbucks

Comment: gsub("I went to( the) [a-z]+","REPLACED", string)

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Yeah, sorry. My mistake. Both ytk and chattrat423 suggestions are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `stringr` package with the following regular expression (anchored at the front of the string using `^`):

```
library(stringr)
sentences <- c("I went to the store last night",
               "I went to the park yesterday",
               "I went to starbucks this morning")
str_replace(sentences, "^I went to( the)?", "REPLACED")
# [1] "REPLACED store last night"       "REPLACED park yesterday"        
# [3] "REPLACED starbucks this morning"
```

If there are multiple instances to replace within the same string, you may want to omit the `^` and use `str_replace_all()`